# Alamofire GET request isn't working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, get, request, alamofire

I am sending out a GET request like so.

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "filter": ["fruit": "apple"]
     ]

Alamofire.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding:URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
           print(response.request!)
     }
```

However, the GET request doesn't work correctly. I believe the parameters are not correct at all. This is the URL request that is printed out using the following code `print(response.request!)`

```
https://api.example.com/fruits?apiKey=1&filter%5Bfruit%5D=apple
```

However, using postman I can send the correct request and get the correct response using the following URL request.

`https://api.example.com/fruits?apiKey=1&filter={"fruit":"apple"}`

I don't know how to fix this. I tried many encoding types, but none of it worked. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated

Edit: I do get a response from the server using alamofire, but it isn't correct data because the paramters are ignored. However, the response I get from postman is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morning Curt,

> Since there is no published specification for how to encode collection types, the convention of appending [] to the key for array values (foo[]=1&foo[]=2), and appending the key surrounded by square brackets for nested dictionary values (foo[bar]=baz) [is used].

In my opinion you should really avoid passing array objects in query strings. You could change your request to something like:

```
apiKey=1&fruit=apple
```

Where does presence of field fruit itself indicates response should be filtered.

Moreover:

> Instead of using GET, you should consider using POST or PUT and passing values via JSON, XML, or another well-defined format. This could require server side changes obviously.
>
> If server side is out of your control, you should consider manually encoding these parameters instead.

[Source](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/329)

[You can find here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482628/post-request-error-with-parameter-encode-when-use-moya-and-alamofire) of manually encoding.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I probably need to do. I have no control of server side, so it looks like I should manual encode it and add it to the end of the url.